# Position an element with animation effect (jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to position an element(elemA) relative to another element(elemB).  So I am using jQuery ui position utility for that, as follows:

```
 $(elemA).position({my:'right top', at:'left top', of:elemB});
```

But I want that positioning to be done with animation effect.

How can I use `.animate()` to achieve my task?

You can see what I've done so far in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRWzx/1/). I want the elemA to slide to the new position with animation effect using jQuery and jQuery ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this??

```
<div>
    <div id="elemA"><button id="btn">click</button></div>

    <div id="elemB"></div>
</div>

$('#btn').click(function(){  
  var position = $('#elemB').offset().left-100; 
  $("#elemA").animate({'left':position},'slow');  

});​
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vRWzx/45/)

Also check the css, i have edited it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *using* option callback of the [`position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) method to animate the element being positioned.

> When specified, the actual property setting is delegated to this callback. Receives two parameters: The first is a hash of top and left values for the position that should be set and can be forwarded to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css) or [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate).

(*Links added by me*)

---

So your code will be:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#elemA').position({
    my: 'right top',
    at: 'left top',
    of: $('#elemB'),
    using: function(pos) {
      $(this).animate(pos, "slow")
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#elemA {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
#elemB {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="elemA">
    <button id="btn">click</button>
  </div>
  <div id="elemB"></div>
</div>
```